# Armar un linq query dependiendo de parámetros

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

Estoy en mi primera aplicación WPF, y voy a hacer una consulta de boletas. Lleva un montón de datos, pero pongo sólo algunos para efecto de ejemplo.

Para solicitar la consulta el usuario podrá seleccionar algunos parámetros, por ejemplo el estatus de las boletas que quiere ver. En este caso pueden ser Todas, Activas o Canceladas, para lo cual le muestro un `ComboBox` para que seleccione. La duda es, no sé cómo armar el query dependiendo de la selección.

En el caso de que pida sólo Canceladas o sólo Activas, no hay problema; pongo esto:

```
lsBoletas = new List<BoletaCL>();
grdBoletas.ItemsSource = null;

string _status = cbEstatus.SelectedValue.ToString();

var boletaQuery = (from b in _context.Boletas
                    where b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaIni) >= 0
                    && b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaFin) <= 0
                    && b.Status.Equals(_status)
                    select b
                            ).ToList();
foreach (var item in boletaQuery)
{
     lsBoletas.Add(new BoletaCL
     {
         Base = item.Base,
         Camion = item.Camion,
         Boleta = item.Boleta
     });
}

grdBoletas.ItemsSource = lsBoletas;
```

y todo funciona bien, pero si solicita Todas, ¿qué debo hacer? ¿Poner otro bloque de código igual a éste, pero sin filtrar el estatus? Y si además de esta selección tengo más similares (con opción a Todo, o una en específico), ¿debo hacer un bloque de código por cada una de ellas?

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta pregunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139467/how-to-create-linq-query-from-string)(ingles). Basicamente te da 3 opciones, aunque yo usaría la tercera(dividir la consulta en varias partes.

Comment: gracias Pikoh esto me funcionó

Comment: De nada. Un placer ayudarle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como menciona Pikoh en su comentario, yo también optaría por dividir la query en diferentes partes para evitar repetir la consulta 2 veces.

Esta es la forma que yo lo haría:

```
string _status = cbEstatus.SelectedValue.ToString();

var boletaQuery = _context.Boletas
                      .Where(b => b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaIni) >= 0
                                  && b.Fecha.CompareTo(FechaFin) <= 0);

if (_status != "Todo") // usa la cadena correcta aquí
{
    boletaQuery = boletaQuery.Where(b => b.Status.Equals(_status));
}

foreach (var item in boletaQuery)
{
    // ...
}
```

Toma en cuenta que, hasta que no comienzes a recorrer los resultados del query (por medio de un `foreach` o un `.ToList()` por ejemplo), no se habrá ejecutado la query todavía, por lo que puedes seguir componiéndola sin problemas.

Comment: A esto exactamente me refería :)

Comment: OK, muchísimas gracias a  @Pikoh y a sstan por el aporte, la verdad desconocía eso, como muchas otras cosas sobre linq, sigo aprendiendo, gracias!!

Comment: Si consideras que la respuesta contesta tu duda correctamente, considera aceptarla para que si alguna otra persona lo necesita sepa que esta respuesta es valida @Cyndy. Y de nada